# Intent.ACTION_VIEW not working when url is google drive and no google account

Tags: android

In my application, i have a button to open the google drive public folder that can be accessed by anyone.
But my problem arise when i tried to run on fresh installed emulator, no signed in google account, and the browser that i have is chrome.

I'm trying to open google drive's url in emulator via `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`, but that's work only when i'm signing in my google account, or i installed another browser like firefox, so that i can show my intent chooser, and pick that firefox to show my google drive url

What i'm confused, when i paste and enter my google drive link on chrome, it successfully load the page, but when i try via intent, it keep showing a toast with message *"Could not find any google accounts, exiting application"*

I've tried set mimetype to `text/html` or `text/plain` but it doesnt give any good result

I only want when the button is clicked, it gonna redirect to browser and open it with or without signing in first,

Is that possible to do something like that? or is my problem here is actually the expected behaviour of the intent or emulator itself?

Thank you

Note:
I only tested this on emulator, because i cant test this on my real device for a reason

Answer (score 0):

This should be the app Google Docs installed in your mobile phone. You can use the following code to let users choose by themselves.

```
public static void openUrlViaChromeBrowser(Context context, String url) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = null;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                resolveInfos = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL);
            }else{
                resolveInfos = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
            }
            List<String> packageNames = new ArrayList<>();
            String targetPkg = "";
            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfos) {
                String pkg = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                packageNames.add(pkg);
                if (pkg.equals("com.android.chrome")){
                    targetPkg = pkg;
                }else if (pkg.toLowerCase().contains("browser")){
                    targetPkg = pkg;
                }
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(targetPkg) && !packageNames.isEmpty()){
                targetPkg = packageNames.get(0);
            }
            intent.setPackage(targetPkg);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```